# Spring Social Login redirect after successful url

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-security

I have spring boot application with social login. I have followed spring-social-showcase example to get social login working. But now I have problem with redirect URL after successful authentication. Signup page works fine. I have configured SpringSecurity as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .apply(getSpringSocialConfigurer())
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**", "/favicon.ico", "/resources/**", "/auth/**", "/signin/**", "/signup/**", "/disconnect/facebook", "/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}

private SpringSocialConfigurer getSpringSocialConfigurer() {
    SpringSocialConfigurer config = new SpringSocialConfigurer();
    config.alwaysUsePostLoginUrl(true);
    config.postLoginUrl("/profile?login=true");

    return config;
}

@Bean
public SocialUserDetailsService socialUserDetailsService() {
    return new SimpleSocialUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
}
```

Comment: I think it's the same as if you had a normal spring security login, which means using a AuthenticationSuccessHandler. If so, i could explain you how but since i am not entirely sure if it really IS the same, i wait for your reaction

Answer (score 0):

Move your SocialConfigurer under .formLogin, it sets the default target url correctly but is then overwritten in form auth.

```
http
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/")
        .and()
        .apply(getSpringSocialConfigurer())
```